# difference between Intel E7 and E5 Xeon models?

Tags: cpu, intel, avx

I'm researching the possibility to build a cluster of powerful machines geared towards HPC (FLOP) computation and therefore I have been reviewing the top [Intel Xeon models](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processor-comparison/compare-intel-processors.html) and was surprise to discover that Xeon E7 models do not support AVX vectorization while the Xeon E5 do. The E7 on the other hand support SSE 4.2 that appears to be an optimization unrelated to FLOP computation and HPC but rather geared to speeding characters computation e.g. XML parsing.

To be sure I got the differences correctly I would like to ask whether this is the case E7 Xeon models do no support AVX and are geared towards "Systems" and E5 Xeon models support AVX and are geared towards HPC intensive FLOP computation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK I found a [good report](http://bladesmadesimple.com/2012/06/4-socket-blade-serverwhich-intel-cpu-do-you-choose/) that answers my question:

```
Comparing the Intel E7-4780 (10 core, 2.4GHz) with an Intel E5-4650 (8 core, 2.7 GHz), 
you’ll find that the E5 server outperforms against the E7 server in the 
following benchmarks:

 - CAE
 - SPECfp*_rate_base2006
 - Numerical Weather
 - Financial Services
 - Life Sciences
 - Linpack AVX
 - SPECint*_rate_base2006

The E7 server outperforms the E5 server in the following benchmarks:

 - java* Middleware
 - OLTP Database
 - Enterprise Resource Planning
```